# Can anyone please explain the output of ls -1 in Linux?

Tags: linux, ls

I was asked this question in one of the interviews.
Can anyone please explain

Comment: To clarify, Do you mean `ls -l` or `ls -1`?

Comment: ls -1 (number 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ls -l shows all files or directories, with their respectives names, sizes, last date and hour of modification, and also all permitions for them.

while ls -1 will list files each on separate line

Answer (score 3):

`ls -1` will list files each on separate line...

[image]

whereas `ls` itself will list them like so

[image]